# generar un excel con laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando generar un excel, desde base de datos, usando  la libreria Maatwebsite en laravel y llo genera "a veces". 
Me da un error: 
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined offset: 0

pero no con todas las tablas de la base de datos; con alguna funciona, con otras no.
El código es sencillo:

```
class MiExcel implements FromCollection, WithStrictNullComparison,  WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '#',
            'Usuario',
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    { 
        return User::all();   
    }
}



class MiExcelController extends Controller
{

    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new MiExcel , 'personas.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Creo que el problema tiene que ver con el índice 0 pero no soy capaz de resolverlo.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Pon el error completo, con la poca informacion  que brindas no podemos reprodicir el problema

Comment: No dice mucho más

Comment: Y no sé cómo puedo mostrarlo. Lo siento

Comment: el error indica que deseas hacer uso de un array sin elementos, y de todas formas lo estas utilizando. Imagina iniciar un array vacio y que posterior desees utilizarlo sin tener datos en el. Ese es tu error no pudes utilizar el array en la posicion 10 si el tu array solo contiene 10 elementos en todo caso el array llegaria solo a la posicion 9.

Comment: en todo caso tu error seria en `return User::all();` (aunque no estoy seguro), seria bueno que realizes tu propia vista de exportacion de datos y no dejar que ` Maatwebsite` decida por ti.

Comment: Muchas gracias. El error estaba en que al pedir la colección entera, tenía objetos anidados y no se pueden traer unos objetos dentro de otros. Posiblemente error de principiante. Pero ya solucionado